# Unable to install signed .bar file in Blackberry Z10

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-10

I am unable to install signed .bar file on Blackberry Z10 (OS Ver. 10.0.10.82) via OTA or through bar file on phone memory. I get a "unable to open myapp.bar" error when I try to install the file. I created this bar file by converting Android app to Blackberry 10 app using Eclipse. I am able to install and run the same bar file properly on the BB10 simulator.

Is this a limitation of Blackberry 10 that we cannot install a bar file using OTA? Is there a workaround available for this?

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated as downloading app via OTA is core requirement of my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install .bar file from your phone.

- You can use [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bb10-playbook-app-manager/kmbaalodpmjjhpobkgljnelbpblnikkp?hl=en) to install it.
- If you are using eclipse, you can install it directly from there

Also, your OS version is antient. Please update it.